# What hardware issue can cause "Battery 2: Not present" in windows 10 (or Ubuntu)

Tags: laptop, battery

So I have two identical tablets. Both have a docking station with keyboard, extra battery and extra HDD. (Medion Akoya S6214T for those interested).
One of the two tablets does not detect the second battery (keyboard and HDD is detected) on both docking stations.

I am sure it is the one tablet because the other tablet detects everything as should be.
I am convinced it is a hardware issue because I installed Ubuntu live on both tablets and I get the same behavior (the one tablet fails to detect the second battery in the docking station).

Funny thing is though: windows 10 displays both batteries in the panel from the taskbar (e.g. Battery 1: 14%, Battery 2: Not present). When showing the total time left before I run out of battery, the second battery is taken into account. For example it might say 2h00 left when it is not docked and 5h00 when docked.

So all and all not a big problem (at least now I know, it is not the battery), but if someone should give some more insight without spending to much time, it would be very welcome.

Thank you!
Bart

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this problem by opening up the tablet and reseating the two connections from the connector to the docking station, to the motherboard.

Thanks for anyone who was interested.